# How do i get emacs syntax highlighting to recognize double quoted strings?

Tags: php, html, emacs

Emacs in html and php modes don't seem to recognize double quoted strings, or at least don't color them correctly. How can i get them to be visible?

Comment: Which Emacs, which HTML mode, and which PHP mode? Furthermore, what do you mean by "don't color them correctly"? (You can get information of the currently enabled modes by typing `C-h m`.)

Comment: Emacs version: 23.1.50.1. It says the mode is actually the xhtml mode which is based on the sgml mode. Single quoted strings are colored black instead of orange like the double quoted strings.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [nxhtml-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/NxhtmlMode).